# Getting the customer email address to success.tpl in OpenCart

Tags: email, variables, opencart

I have been able to get the order_id and the total order value to process them on the success page in OpenCart (v. 1.5.4) by applying the very helpful suggestions of Shadyyx (thank you!) in [Opencart successful order ID and Total from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960418/opencart-successful-order-id-and-total-from-javascript). However, I have been unable to get the email address of the (registered or guest) customer across, i.e.:

If I insert `$this->data['email'] = $this->session->data ['email'];` in success.php before `$this->cart->clear();`

I get an Undefined Index error in success.php when submitting an order.

If I insert `$this->data['email'] = $this->cart->getEmail();`

instead, I avoid the Undefined Index error, but still the email address does not load in the html form via the input tag (this does, however, work for the order_id and the total) as follows:

`<?php if(!empty($email)): ?`>
`<input name="email" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $email ?>">`
`<?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this properly you need to open `/catalog/controller/checkout/success.php` and find this line of code

```
if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {
```

After it, add the following

```
    $this->load->model('account/order');
    $order = $this->model_account_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);
    if($order) {
        $this->data['email'] = $order['email'];
    }
```

In your template `/catalog/view/theme/your-theme-name/template/common/success.tpl` you need to put

```
<?php if(!empty($email)) echo $email; ?>
```

Wherever you want to see the e-mail address

Answer (score 0):

`$this->customer->getEmail();` - this will get you logged in customer's email id.

In `catalog/controller/checkout/success.php`, insert the below code between

`if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {`

and

`$this->cart->clear();`

**Code to add:**

```
if (isset($this->session->data['guest'])) { 
    $this->data['customer_email'] = $this->session->data['guest']['email'];  // Guest user's email
} elseif($this->customer->isLogged()) {
    $this->data['customer_email'] = $this->customer->getEmail(); // Customer's email
}
```

Then in success.tpl, add:

```
<?php if(isset($customer_email)){ ?>
<input name="email" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $customer_email ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the very quick reply!It was almost perfect! Your solution works perfectly for the customer email, but no value comes through for the guest email. Could it be that the variable name for the guest email is different? In success.php the relevant 3 lines that process the email address in the form (whether guest or customer) are: '<?php if(!empty($email)): ?>' '<input name="email" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $email ?>">' '<?php endif; ?>'