# Custom meta title on checkout/success page in opencart

Tags: seo, opencart, meta-title

I am new to opencart and need help with oc 1.5.5.1

I am trying to call custom meta title to add last order id on checkout/success page. I have followed a very helpfull response from shadyyx on [Opencart successful order ID and Total from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960418/opencart-successful-order-id-and-total-from-javascript)

Now I am stuck at a point on how to use the order_id which is already available  in session and call / display it in meta title of checkout/success page.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you, you need to check if the orderid exists and not empty and route is checkout/success so for example add this to $this->data['my-new-metatag']
All above do in the common/header controller (cos meta tags are in the common/header tpl file)

then in common/header.tpl check if $my-new-metatag exists, echo it, otherwise leave variable that echos by default